# symfony2 creating custom field type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi Im trying to create custom field
like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) but after adding to `service.yml`

```
services:
    griffin.type.datetime_to_string:
        class: griffin\CoreBundle\Form\DateTimeType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: datetime_to_string }
```

Im getting `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to griffin\CoreBundle\Form\DataTransformer\DateTimeToStringTransformer::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, null given` any one had this problem ?

EDIT

```
namespace griffin\CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use griffin\CoreBundle\Form\DataTransformer\DateTimeToStringTransformer;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
/**
 * Description of DateTimeType
 *
 * @author skowron-line
 */
class DateTimeType extends AbstractType {

    private $om;

    public function __construnct(ObjectManager $om) {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        var_dump($this->om);
        $transformer = new DateTimeToStringTransformer($this->om);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'invalid_message' => 'err',
        ));
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'datetime_to_string';
    }
}
```

and in my controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new KlientType(), $klient);
```

Comment: please add the code of your DateTimeType as well as how you're instantiating the form in your controller.

Comment: Is there a reason you have your own griffin\CoreBundle\Form\DataTransformer\DateTimeToStringTransformer ( which throws the exception ) instead of just using the one provided by Symfony? ( http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer.html )

Comment: @nifr I want it to be `text` field not `select` becouse I want to add there datepicker

Comment: if you still want to extend the field type because you want to use a custom twig template ( providing a js-datepicker how i suggest ) you only need the getParent function to return 'date' and can ommit the rest :)

Comment: Ok, but still I dont knwo why service is not passing entity manager as constructor parameter ?

Comment: Ah i got it i think ... updating my answer :)

Comment: you added your custom type with "new DateTimeType()" into your parent form instead of using the service name, did you?

Comment: Did my latest edit help you solve the DI problem or does it still exist even after making sure you add the custom field by it's service alias?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom FormType as a service ( because you need to have services or parameters injected ) you must add the field to your builder with it's service name (or alias) and not with new CustomFormType().

```
$builder->add('date', 'datetime_to_string', array(
    // ...
))
```

DateTime to string conversion is already provided by Symfony since 2.0.

Have a look at [Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer.htm)

You can transform the date field into a text input with the "widget" option set to "single_text" and the format option set to your desired text-representation.

```
$builder->add('publishedAt', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
));
```

Transformed into a text input this field can easily be integrated with common JavaScript Datepickers. Consider using that one instead of your own implementation.

**Tip:**

You don't have to surround the injected service with " in yml.

```
services:
    griffin.type.datetime_to_string:
        class: griffin\CoreBundle\Form\DateTimeType
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: datetime_to_string }
```

This often leads to errors when copy/pasting from tutorials on the net where symbols are auto-converted into something different than "real" question marks.

Comment: You don't have but you can and it works. I don't think it is the issue here

Comment: I know - you're generally better off recommending not using them as people tend to copy/paste from homepages/tutorials where those are sometimes auto-converted to something other than "real" quotation marks. had one of these issues here lately :)

Comment: If I dont put `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` in quotes netbeans show this as error

Comment: That is a Netbeans issue happening with eclipse's YAML aswell but it's correct for symfony's YAML implementation.

Comment: But If I do like you show I get 3 input fields, and I want just one

Comment: no problemo :) Updated the answer ... "widget" => "single_text" is what you're looking for! acceptable now?